# How To Save The Output Of Tiny C Compiler Into A File?

Tags: command-prompt, io-redirection, tcc

I Wanna Save The Output Of The C Compiler Named tcc. Tryed Using Redirections In Windows 7 Command Prompt But It Generates An Empty File And Writes The Output In The Command Prompt.

This Is What I Use In Command Prompt:

```
tcc -o test.exe test.c > log.txt
```

Comment: Try `tcc -o test.exe test.c 2> log.txt` (should redirect `stderr` instead of `stdout` to the logfile. But I'm not sure about this on windows.

Comment: Tanks A Lot. Please Write Post It As Answer So I Can Accept It. Can You Please Give Me A Resource To Learn More About The Number Before >?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple output streams a program can write to, in particular there are the default streams `stdout` and `stderr`. Other streams can be files, network connections and much more.

The standard stream `stderr` is usually used to output error messages and debug info, `stdout` is usually used to output the result of a program. What exactly is written to each stream depends on the program.

The `stdout` stream has identifier 1, `stdout` has identifier 2. The number in front of the `>` identifies which stream to redirect. If there is no number given, `1>` is assumed.

You can read more about this [here](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Windows_PowerShell_1.0_Pipes_and_Redirection), it should give you some keywords to search.